# Creating a Database Software needed

Tags: database

Hi can someone explain to me what the following database software are:
HeidiSQL, MariaDB and XAMPP.
Also do they depend on each other to work? Hope you can help.

Thank You

Comment: Hi, this is not really a question for stackoverflow.  Try asking the question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**MariaDB:**

Is a open-source database server, basically its a fork of MySQL and they provide support and services, its slightly better than MySQL since they have made some changes to MySQL. MariaDB doesn't depend on anything. Its a complete database product.

**HeidiSQL:**

Its a fronend-MySQL, its nothing but a UI for interacting with different database servers like MariaDB, Percona, and many more depending on their enhancement. HeidiSQL is just a frond end, If you want to interact with databases, you must connect to one. Yes, heidiSQL is dependent on databases. Latest enhancements support MS SQL Server, which is great :)

**XAMPP:**

Its like a tech stack similar to LAMP, WAMP etc. XAMPP means Apache HTTP Web Server, MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. X stands for cross platform. XAMPP is dependent on many as you can see its a tech stack.